# Segmentation fault при разыменовании

Tags: c++, boost, lua, segmentation-fault

Что я делаю не так?:

```
boost::any value = ...

...

void* ud = lua_newuserdata(lua, sizeof(boost::any));

*reinterpret_cast<boost::any*>(ud) = value;
```

Segmentation fault и если просто сделать `malloc(sizeof(boost::any))`

Comment: Надо еще инициализировать объект вызвав конструктор при помощи placement new.

Comment: А просто `printf("%d", sizeof(boost::any))` катит?

Comment: Меня смутило то, что код работал, если его скопипастить в новый проект. Разобрался. `new (ud) boost::any(value)`